# Post a review to a product using BazarVoice in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, review

I have tried the following code to write a review for a product but it's  not getting inserted into DB. I have replaced the actual value with generic text ex: product value as (ID).

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultSessionConfiguration];

    // Setup the request with URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/submitreview.json?apiversion=5.4&ProductId=(ID)&UserId=(ID)&passkey=(PassKey)"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Convert POST string parameters to data using UTF8 Encoding
NSString *postParams = @"IsRecommended=true&Rating=5&Title=Nice+One!&ReviewText=Good&UserNickname=RR";
NSData *postData = [postParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Convert POST string parameters to data using UTF8 Encoding
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Create dataTask
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // Handle your response here

    if(error == nil)
    {
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
        NSLog(@"%@",responseDictionary);
    }

    if(completionBlock)
        completionBlock(nil,error);
}];

    // Fire the request
[dataTask resume];
```

Below is the response which I am getting from the API. It gives success response but review is not getting inserted into DB.

```
{
AuthorSubmissionToken = "<null>";
Data =     {
FormErrors =     {
};
HasErrors = 0;
Locale = "en_US";
Review =     {
    Id = "<null>";
    IsRecommended = 1;
    Rating = 5;
    ReviewText = Good;
    SendEmailAlertWhenCommented = 0;
    SendEmailAlertWhenPublished = 0;
    SubmissionId = "<null>";
    SubmissionTime = "2017-05-25T07:47:27.520+00:00";
    Title = "Nice One!";
    TypicalHoursToPost = "<null>";
};
SubmissionId = "<null>";
TypicalHoursToPost = 72;
```

}

I have referred to https://developer.bazaarvoice.com/conversations-api/getting-started/submission-fundamentals#overview link from BazarVoice documentation.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No... It gives success response.. Updated my question.

Comment: are you following this link : https://developer.bazaarvoice.com/conversations-api/reference/v5.4/reviews/review-submission#submit-a-review

Comment: Yes.. I have followed that.. But I didn't send value for "fp" key. I didn't understand what to send for that after reading their documentation. Could it be the reason?

Comment: I think you need to send the fp value as well.